# Preference Activity with MenuDrawer

Tags: android, preferenceactivity

I am using SimonVT excellent [MenuDrawer library](https://github.com/SimonVT/android-menudrawer) to develop my app. I based my code on [Wordpress Android app](http://android.wordpress.org/development/) (which is open-source). Following this code, I created a base Activity class that all my activities extend. For reference, [this](http://android.svn.wordpress.org/trunk/src/org/wordpress/android/ui/WPActionBarActivity.java) is the base class I based my code upon.

I want to create a Configuration screen with settings for my app, that includes my MenuDrawer slide menu, and thus incorporates all functionality of this base activity class. The problem is, all information I could find about creating preference activities rely on extending PreferenceActivity, which I obviously can't do since I want to extend the mentioned base class.

Is there any way to take advantage of xml preferences definition without using a PrefernceActivity? Please note that I'm targetting Android 2.3

Answer (score 0):

I guess you could use a PreferenceFragment instead of a PreferenceActivity: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/settings.html#Fragment

But PreferenceFragment only exists for Android 3.0 and higher.

Alternatively you could essentially duplicate WPActionBarActivity as WPPreferenceActivity or something like that and extend this new class from SherlockPreferenceActivity (and maybe skip irrelevant code from WPActionBarActivity in the process).

This would enable you to stay compatible with older Android versions.

If you want to avoid duplicating the menudrawer-related code between those two classes, you could draw this code out effectively refactoring it into its own Utility-like class into static methods with the current context as parameter and any other parameters you might need.